# Sitecore publish site in multi site tenancy

Tags: sitecore

We have two Sitecore 6.5 sites defined within one Sitecore instance so our structure is

/sitecore/content/Site1
/sitecore/content/Site2

If a user selects a site in the Sitecore backend, and then Publishes the site, will Sitecore then publish just the selected site or both the sites within the Sitecore instance?

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box Sitecore will publish everything from both sites on a "site publish"- you can resolve this by:

1. Dead simple approach: just do an "item publish" on the desired site root and include subitems.
2. Configure a custom publish target as described by John West: http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-Publishing-Targets-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you have 2 sets of users, i.e. one role for each site with the correct read/write permissions set, then you could restrict what gets published using security.

In config set `Publishing.CheckSecurity` to `true`

> If you set Publishing.CheckSecurity to true, then members of the
>   Sitecore Client Publishing role must have both read and write access
>   in order to publish an item. If you additionally set the
>   Publishing.RequireTargetDeleteRightWhenCheckingSecurity setting in the
>   web.config file to true, then the user must have delete access in the
>   item in the target database to publish a deletion.

Of course, if a user belongs to both roles then that still means both sites will be published, you can just publish an item and sub-items

- [Use Default or Custom Access Rights to Control Whether Users Can Publish an Item](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/08/Use-a-Custom-Access-Right-to-Control-Whether-Users-Can-Publish-an-Item.aspx)
- [Publishing Security Basics](http://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/publishing-security-basics/)